# How to dynamic UISwitch in TableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to do dynamic switch in a tableview

Ex.I have 4 elements of UISwitch.
- All
- 1
- 2
- 3

When i turn off All and other Switch must turn off, and if i turn on other switch and All is off

How i can do this. I cannot get indexPath or get identify of Switch

Please helpme.
PS.Sorry my English

Comment: Do you mean you have one switch per tableView cell?
Why do you require them in a tableView at all?

Answer (score 1):

The state of the switches should set through your datasource. So if you click "all" on one of them, you can loop through your datasource, set the state for all switches and reload the table view.